# Is there a R function to rescale coordinates from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, scale, spatial, r-sp

I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object with polygon coordinates in meters (UTM). I would like to rescale the coordinates to kilometers (divide the coordinates by 1000). Is there a function in the `sp` package that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

My workaround, where TiogaHabitatBoundary is a shapefile of polygons. https://mhallwor.github.io/_pages/basics_SpatialPolygons was a great resource.

```
TiogaHabitat<- readOGR("TiogaHabitatBoundary.shp")
TiogaHabitat<-spTransform(TiogaHabitat, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=NAD83")) #transform to UTMs

#Extract coordinates and put them in a list
extractCoords <- function(sp.df)
{
  results <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(sp.df@polygons[[1]]@Polygons))
  {
    results[[i]] <- sp.df@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords
  }
  results
}

vertices<-extractCoords(TiogaHabitat)

#Divide coordinates by 1,000
meters.to.km<-function(meters){
  km<-meters/1000
}

scaled.vertices<-lapply(vertices, meters.to.km)

#Create Polygons and Spatial Polygons Data Frame from scaled list of coordinates
Polys<-list()
for(i in 1:length(scaled.vertices)){
  Polys[i]<-sp::Polygon(scaled.vertices[[i]])
}
Polys.plural<-sp::Polygons(Polys, ID = "0")
Polys.sp<-sp::SpatialPolygons(list(Polys.plural), proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=NAD83"))
Tioga.spdf<-sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Polys.sp, data = TiogaHabitat@data)
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).